# Node Mongo - find multiple parameters

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to find in a collection if there is already a session number, to avoid duplications. dadosORS.email and dadosORS.sessao (which is 3)come from a form. So when I do this:

```
mongoClient.collection('registosORS', function(err,collection){
  collection.find({email:{$eq:dadosORS.email}},{sessao:{$eq:dadosORS.sessao}}).toArray(function(err,result){

                    try{
                    console.log(result);
                    }catch (err){
                      console.log(err);                          
                    }

                      if(result){
                        // callback(false)
                        return
                      } else {
```

I get result = undefined. If I change the query to

```
 collection.find({email:dadosORS.email},{sessao:dadosORS.sessao}).toArray(function(err,result){
```

it lists my every occurence of the email:

```
      [ { _id: 5a37b4c3da53ff1e825f94b4, sessao: '1' },
{ _id: 5a37b4e6da53ff1e825f94b6, sessao: '1' },
    { _id: 5a37b57ce500ca1ea5522e22, sessao: '2' } ]
```

So, how can I see if the dadosORS.sessao for that dadosORS.email already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do an `and` query:

```
 collection.find( { email : dadosORS.email, sessao : dadosORS.sessao } )
```

or can be expressed as

```
 collection.find( { $and: [ { email : dadosORS.email }, { sessao : dadosORS.sessao } ] } )
```